# Problem with Leaderboard (High score) system

Tags: java, leaderboard

I have a leaderboard class in my java game but it doesn't work exactly how I want it to. I have 3 scores that display when you click into the leaderboard button, 1st, 2nd and 3rd. The problem I'm having is that whenever I get a score that should replace the 2nd score it won't change the 3rd score. So, for example:

```
1st = 10
2nd = 8
3rd = 5
```

if I score 9 in the game it would look like:

```
1st = 10
2nd = 9
3rd = 5
```

I want it to where the 3rd score is replaced with the original 2nd score so it would look like:

```
1st = 10
2nd = 9
3rd = 8
```

Any help in how I might achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

My code:

```
 TextView tvScore, tvPersonalBest, tvSecondBest, tvThirdBest;

 int score = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("score");
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);

        int scoreSP = pref.getInt("scoreSP",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

        int scoreSB = pref.getInt("scoreSB",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorr = pref.edit();

        int scoreTB = pref.getInt("scoreTB",0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editorrr = pref.edit();

        if(score > scoreSP){
            scoreSP = score;
            editor.putInt("scoreSP", scoreSP);
            editor.commit();
        }
        if(score > scoreTB && score < scoreSP){
            scoreSB = score;
            editorr.putInt("scoreSB", scoreSB);
            editorr.commit();
        }
        if(score < scoreSB && score > scoreTB){
            scoreTB = score;
            editorrr.putInt("scoreTB", scoreTB);
            editorrr.commit();
        }
        tvScore = findViewById(R.id.tvScore);
        tvPersonalBest = findViewById(R.id.tvPersonalBest);
        tvSecondBest = findViewById(R.id.secondBest);
        tvThirdBest = findViewById(R.id.thirdBest);
        tvScore.setText(""+score);
        tvPersonalBest.setText(""+scoreSP);
        tvSecondBest.setText(""+scoreSB);
        tvThirdBest.setText(""+scoreTB);


    }
```

Comment: put the scores in list and sort the list

Comment: Well, your code does not do any shifting. You have to go in the two first cases, `score > scoreSP` and the next one and add according code. Or better, store the whole data as a list, and when a new value comes in, append it and sort the list.